# JMockit injecting nested member variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmockit

I am currently attempting to test the execution path of my code, but I ran into some issues when it came to nested class member variables. Consider the following class structure:

```
System (System under test)
 -> ClassA
   -> ClassB
     -> ClassC
```

A class named `System` contains an instance of `ClassA`, and will invoke one of its methods. `ClassA` will similarly contain an instance of `ClassB` and will invoke one of it's methods, etc.

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SomeTest {
    @Tested
    private System system;

    @Injectable
    private ClassA memberA;

    @Injectable
    private ClassB memberB;

    @Injectable
    private ClassC memberC;

    @Test
    public void doSystemTest() {
        // Do stuff
        system.handle();

        new Verifications() {
            {
                system.handle(); times = 1;
                memberA.doSomeAStuff(); times = 1;
                memberB.doSomeBStuff(); times = 1; // Results in test failure: 
            }
        };
    }
}
```

When I run this test, I get the following error:

> Missing 1 invocation to:
>   ca.kgli.jmockit.ClassB#doSomeBStuff()
>      on mock instance: ca.kgli.jmockit.ClassB@1a052a00

For reference, here is the code:

```
public class System {
    private ClassA memberA;

    public void handle() {
        memberA.doSomeAStuff();
    }
}

public class ClassA {
    private ClassB memberB;

    public void doSomeAStuff() {
        memberB.doSomeBStuff();
    }
}

public class ClassB {
    private ClassC member;

    public void doSomeBStuff() {
        member.stuffCSays("arsenic");
    }
}

public class ClassC {
    public String stuffCSays(String input) {
        return "Hello, " + input;
    }
}
```

So my question is, why is the method `doSomeBStuff` not being invoked? Was JMockit not meant to be used in this way? I'm new to this test toolkit so any help or insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: memberA is being injected as a mock, meaning that all its methods have no implementation (unless defined otherwise using results and returns) so memberA is not really calling menberB, and that is completely alright in Unit testing. You should limit the tests on System.java as verifying that the call is being delegated to memberA. Then have a ClassA Test verifyng that memberB is being used, and so on

Comment: Thanks! I guess that confirms my suspicion all along. Seems like the JMockit was just not designed to be used this way, which makes sense in the context of unit testing.

Comment: What you are looking for is `@Tested(fullyInitialized = true)`, which allows all classes to be tested from the call to `System#doSystemTest()`, with no mocking. See [Getting started](http://jmockit.github.io/gettingStarted.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you mock `ClassA`, the real implemention of `doSomeAStuff()` is intercepted by Jmockit, so it will not call `doSomeBStuff()`.

You should only mock `ClassA` when you perform unit test on `System`.

```
@RunWith(JMockit.class)
public class SomeTest {
    @Tested
    private System1 system;

    @Injectable
    private ClassA memberA;

    @Test
    public void doSystemTest() {
        // Do stuff
        system.handle();

        new Verifications() {
            {
                memberA.doSomeAStuff(); times = 1;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The mock of `ClassB` should only occur when you perform unit test on `ClassA`.